# How to add class to parent span of input type radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one doubt with `jQuery`. I have an `HTML` structure as follow:

```
<div class="radio" id="uniform-op21">
    <span>
        <input type="radio" value="2" id="op21" name="op11" style="opacity: 0;">
    </span>
</div>
```

I want to add a class using `addClass()` of `jQuery` using *id* of input type radio that is op21. I am unable to write code.

when I use the following code:

```
$("#op11").parent().addClass("checkbox");
```

Then it is adding *class* to `<div>` instead of `<span>`. How can I add class to `<span>` tag using this `id` ?

**`update` :**

Sorry, Actually the complete code structure is as follow :

```
<div style="margin-left:60px;font-size:14px;" class="checked">
    <div class="radio" id="uniform-op11"><span><input type="radio" value="1" id="op11" name="op11" style="opacity: 0;"></span></div>Indira gandhi<br><br>
    <div class="radio" id="uniform-op21"><span><input type="radio" value="2" id="op21" name="op11" style="opacity: 0;"></span></div>Rajendra Singh<br><br>
    <div class="radio" id="uniform-op31"><span><input type="radio" value="3" id="op31" name="op11" style="opacity: 0;"></span></div>Rahul Gandi<br><br>
    <div class="radio" id="uniform-op41"><span><input type="radio" value="4" id="op41" name="op11" style="opacity: 0;"></span></div>Narendra Modi<br><br>
    <div class="radio" id="uniform-zero"><span><input type="radio" value="0" id="zero" name="op21" style="opacity: 0;"></span></div>Narendra Modi<br><br>
    </div>
```

I want to add the class on the span of input of id `zero`, When I am using the code

```
$("#zero").parent().addClass("checked");
```

Then It is directly adding the class on the div on the first line. How can I add this, these span tags are added already

Comment: your html has id `op21` and your jquery `op11`.

Comment: It works correctly if you use the right selector: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/SQsZS/2/

Comment: ok i will add a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just your id mistake.Your Jquery is correct:

[SEE THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gXD2w/2/)

```
$("#op11").parent().addClass("checkbox");

$(document).ready(function(){
alert(document.getElementById('uniform-op21').innerHTML);
});
```

**Note in the alert you can see the class added to the span.**

---

[SEE THIS FIDDLE IN WHICH SPAN OF EVERY INPUT IS ADDED WITH class=checkbox](http://jsfiddle.net/gXD2w/3/)

Answer (score 2):

You can Try:

```
$('#op21').closest('span').addClass('checkbox');

Or

$('#op21').parent().addClass('checkbox');
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tksLy/)**

Comment: @lord_linus: When do you want to add that class?? On click of radio button i guess??

Comment: the main problem is that I will hide that radio button and want to send this as default value, because the jQuery code for checking the radio button is checked or not value is not working for me

Comment: @lord_linus:What if user wants to change the option. You should check on submit button that which radio box is checked and work accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Simply change `$("#op11")` to `$("#op21")`. Other than that, your code is fine.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/SQsZS/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong, you want the parent of `#op21` not `#op11`.

```
$("#op21").parent().addClass("checkbox");
```

Also you *should* close your `input` element with `/>`:

```
<input type="radio" value="2" id="op21" name="op11" style="opacity: 0;" />
```

Comment: The first one isn't a problem. Self-closing tags are valid in HTML4.

Comment: Self-closing tags are valid in HTML5, but not required.

Comment: You're right, my editor complains so I'm used to closing all tags.  Updated answer for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrong with your jQuery selector

**As your code :**

```
<input id="op21" name="op11">
```

*(short version for more understanding)*

**Your jQuery :**

`$("#op11")` = `<input id="op11">`(It's wrong) (your input id is `op21`)

**So correct is :**

```
$("#op21")
```

Select by id (# = id) [(ID Selector)](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

or

```
$("input[name='op11']")
```

Select by attr `name` [(Attribute Equals Selector)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

---

[Learn more about selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

---

Edited : `$('#zero')`

Comment: Read my answer and try and read given docs, You will know better about jQuery selectors and not only this case @lord_linus

Comment: I have done that but the class checked at the first div i.e.  `<div style="margin-left:60px;font-size:14px;" class="checked">`